# Write a text file for each row in a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Name  Seq
a     atcg
b     ggct
c     ccga
```

I wish to create individual text files for each row, where named the file is named based on one column and the file contents are based on another column.

I currently have this code:

```
import csv
with open('prac.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        file_name ='{0}.txt'.format(row['name']) 
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            pass
```

Which creates text files with the values in the 'Name' column for each row. However I am unsure how to write the 'Seq' column to each text file.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close:

```
import csv
with open('prac.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)                              #you can remove this, see below
        file_name ='{0}.txt'.format(row['Name']) 
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(row['Seq'])
```

I added the `print` statement just to show what each "`row`" is; you already key the `Name` when creating `file_name`, you just need to key `Seq` when writing:

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'a'), ('Seq', 'atcg')])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'b'), ('Seq', 'ggct')])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'c'), ('Seq', 'ccga')])
```